# Not converting flv file to mp4 file using ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg, centos

I installled ffmpeg for my centos server.then i converted my flv files to mp4 by using ffmpeg.But its creating 0 byte error mp4 file.
Conversion code

```
shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i ffmpeg/test1.flv-c copy -copyts ffmpeg/test.mp4');
```

ffmpeg version is

```
ffmpeg version N-75682-g5fa5e73 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
  configuration:
  libavutil      55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
  libavcodec     57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
  libavformat    57.  2.102 / 57.  2.102
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6.  9.101 /  6.  9.101
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfi     
le}...
```

After run this i am getting the below output

```
ffmpeg version N-75682-g5fa5e73 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
  configuration:
  libavutil      55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
  libavcodec     57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
  libavformat    57.  2.102 / 57.  2.102
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6.  9.101 /  6.  9.101
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
Input #0, flv, from 'ffmpeg/test1.flv':
  Metadata:
    starttime       : 0
    totalduration   : 67
    totaldatarate   : 354
    bytelength      : 2954448
    canseekontime   : true
    sourcedata      : BD075F34AHM1443878448533564
    purl            :
    pmsg            :
    httphostheader  : r7---sn-xupn5a5u-4wge7.googlevideo.com
  Duration: 00:01:06.63, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 354 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: flv1, yuv420p, 426x240, 288 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn                                                                                                                                                             , 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, mono, s16p, 65 kb/s
[aac @ 0x2b4b640] The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are                                                                                                                                                              not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
```

Comment: you should really post the exact output/stacktrace of ffmpeg when invoking /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i ffmpeg/test.avi -c copy -copyts ffmpeg/test.mp4

Comment: Now its working....Thank u seba.wagner for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i ffmpeg/test1.flv -strict -2 ffmpeg/test1.mp4
```

It will work.

Comment: Thank u Basil for your valuable answer